# How to fetch previous link value from session when clicked on multiple links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to fetch previous clicked link value using AJAX and sessions in PHP. But I am getting the current value only. Here's the code I am using.

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();

if(isset($_POST['getpage'])){
    $page = $_POST['pagename'];
    $_SESSION['current'] = $page;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['previous'])){
        $_SESSION['previous'] = "null";
        $_SESSION['previousnew'] = $_SESSION['current'];
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['previous'] == "null"){
        $_SESSION['previous'] = $_SESSION['previousnew'];
        $_SESSION['previousnew'] = $_SESSION['current'];
    }
    else
        $_SESSION['previous'] = $_SESSION['previousnew'];

    print_r($_SESSION);
    exit();
}

$value = 5;

$arr = array("file1","file2","file3","file4");
foreach ( $arr as $k => $v){
    echo "<a href='".$v.".php' onclick='return createpage(\"$v\");'> ".$v." </a><br>";
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function createpage (page){
    var name = page+".php";
    $.post("pageone.php",{getpage : 1,pagename:name},function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**Update**

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();

if(isset($_POST['getpage'])){
$page = $_POST['pagename'];
$_SESSION['current'] = $page;

if(!isset($_SESSION['previous'])){

$_SESSION['previous'] = "null";
$_SESSION['previousnew'] = $_SESSION['current'];
}
elseif($_SESSION['previous'] == "null"){
 $_SESSION['previous'] = $_SESSION['previousnew'];
 $_SESSION['previousnew'] = $_SESSION['current'];
}
else $_SESSION['previous'] = $_SESSION['previousnew'];



$file_pointer = fopen( $_POST['pagename'], 'w' );

$string = '<?php include_once("pageone.php");?>
<?php $var = "'.$_POST["pagename"].'";?>
<?php echo $var;?>
<?php echo "'.$_SESSION["previous"].'";?>
';

fwrite( $file_pointer, $string );

fclose($file_pointer);
exit();
}



$value = 5;

$arr = array("file1","file2","file3","file4");


foreach ( $arr as $k => $v){
echo "<a href='".$v.".php' onclick='return createpage(\"$v\");'> ".$v." </a><br>";
}

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function createpage (page){
var name = page+".php";
$.post("pageone.php",{getpage : 1,pagename:name},function(data){
    //alert(data);
});
return true;
}
</script>
```

Here , I am creating new pages but i cant fetch what i hv clicked previously . That's what i want to chieve.

Comment: Wouldn't you create a cookie and then retrieve that cookie?

Comment: I haven't used them i know sessions so isn't it possible with sessions ?

Comment: you are ajaxing to the same page

Comment: To keep it simple simply post the var of the page to the URL then use a get to grab it then you have it. Simple, clean and easy

Comment: @LeviZoesch What's wrong with session variables?

Comment: Not saying there is anything wrong.

Comment: But the problem is . I want previous link back to new link . how that can be achieved.??

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If I try your code and click on 'file1', I get `Array([current] => file1.php, [previous] => null, [previousnew] => file1.php)`. A subsequent click on 'file2' alerts `Array([current] => file2.php,[previous] => file1.php,[previousnew] => file2.php)`. Do you also get this? What is your expected behavior?

Comment: see my new update @ Martin Koetsier

Comment: @madalinivascu but when i use diffent page the session doesn't retain

Comment: you want to click 1 link - save link href then click again alert the previous clicked link href?

Comment: @madalinivascu  yes you are getting right . Because i have further use of that previous link . Could you do this??

Comment: Are those new files (file1.php, file2.php, etc) actually created on the server? Btw.: I see HUGE security issues with an approach where files are created with a non-checked POST value. What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the bigger picture?

Comment: What kind of security issues ?? @MartenKoetsier

Comment: Well, for example, someone could do a lot of POSTs and fill up the server with random files. Also, this may lead to execution of random code (especially since the file name is also printed into the file, what if the file name contains a `"`?). This is also why I asked what the bigger picture is. Is this the right approach? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: But i am not using post system to my footer . Its just simple text . See my conversation with madalin ivascu

Answer (score 0):

try sessionStorage:

```
function createpage (page){
if (sessionStorage.getItem('href')) {
alert(sessionStorage.getItem('href'));
}
sessionStorage.setItem('href', $(this).attr('href'));
}
```

Comment: But this will show all other pages url which i dont want to use . Session will store those specific pages only which i have written in array . I s it not possible with php sessions ??

Comment: what all other pages?

Comment: Ok the thing is i am creating a footer that contains 40 pages . Which contains just a simple text only for every link  so instead of creating those pages i am dynamically creating those pages and delete them as user move to other and data will be called from database . So thats why i have used sessions . It will save lot of space

Comment: a footer isn't suppose to contain 40 pages a footer is a page footer that contains html elements text/pictures not whole pages

Comment: no i meant 40 links that will go to those pages just like footer of this stackoverflow . links only

Comment: so you want to save the url of the link so when you click and open new page you use that saved value to do something?

Comment: Yes if i get previous value from session then it will get deleted automatically as user move to another link of footer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98220/discussion-between-madalin-ivascu-and-share-fun).